# AWS SDK calls from a Lambda take longer than 30 seconds

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a NodeJs Lambda function in AWS which needs to read some data. As a data source we've tried two options - `S3` and `DynamoDB`. Both on them have the same issue - when we conduct load testing (10 req/sec during 100sec) some requests to those `S3/DynamoDB` fail to complete in 30 sec, which is our Lambda timeout. The requests themselves are very light - for `S3` it is a 1KB file and for `DynamoDB` it is a table with only **one** record in it. On average those requests take less than 100ms, but sometimes we get these very long peaks I'm talking about.

The rate of such long requests is quite small - less than 1%, but this is still not acceptable for us. Moreover, I don't see any reasons why we have such long responses.

Another thing we've noticed is that those 30sec+ requests usually happen after long periods (4h or more) of not calling those `S3/DynamoDB` resources.

The only reason I can think of is that after long inactivity periods AWS infrastructure unable to create required number of ENIs fast enough. ENIs are needed because both `S3` and `DynamoDB` are called via HTTP by `aws-sdk`. But this is just a guess which I don't know how to validate.

Currently, I'm thinking of warming-up ENIs by making requests to `S3/DynamoDB`, but I haven't tried it yet.

If anybody has had similar issues I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix the issue.

P.S. Increasing a Lambda timeout is not an options for us. 30secs are more than enough to make such a simple calls.

Comment: How many WCUs does your DynamoDB table have assigned?

Comment: Can you verify if the delay was S3/Dynamo or Lambda? My guess is Lambda , since S3/Dynamo is always available. For example if your bucket is public there should be no delay if you simply access it via the public URL.

Comment: @Gapton, no the delay is in S3/Dynamo. I measure time of the request to S3/Dynamo, not the time of the Lambda execution. And my S3 is not public, it only accessible inside our VPC for our Lambdas.

Comment: @Stu, my WCU/RCU are default 5/5. I don't write anything during load test, but I see your point. If my understanding of your question is correct the issue might be that there're insufficient RCUs. I also see some errors shown on the "User errors (Count)" metrics graph - they might be 400th errors returned when requests are throttled (according to this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html). I'll try to rise RCUs and check the idea.

Do you have any ideas similar S3 issue? My idea is that S3 has SLA less than 98%.